# Non-standard SSL Port added in url

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, url, nginx, port

I am trying to force using port number in url like https://example.com:8180 while making sure my nginx is serving the web WITH SSL. Is that possible? what is the configuration needed to do that?

Comment: Trying to force... what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default SSL port is 443. You can configure nginx to listen on a different port while still using SSL like so:

`listen 8180 ssl;`

Put that in your `server` block and you're good to go.

See the `listen` docs for more info: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen